# How I do Exclude Android Project Submodule's test from Gradle test

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have one library(A) as a submodule in my android application.

```
android-app
   |---app
   |    |
   |    |--main
   |    |--test
   |
   |--library(A)
        |
        |--main
        |--test
```

When I try to run `gradlew test`, it is executing `libarary(A)`'s test cases along with my app test cases.

How I can exclude my library project test cases from gradle execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            //disable crashlytics build id every time for development
            ext.alwaysUpdateBuildId = false

            // Run code coverage reports by default on debug builds.
            testCoverageEnabled = true
        }

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

```
    //publishNonDefault true
    productFlavors {
        beta {
            //applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
            versionNameSuffix "-beta"
            dimension "green"
        }

        production {
            applicationId "com.example"
            dimension "green"
        }
    }
```

Let's assume that you have build type(debug & release) and flavours(beta & production).

`./gradlew testProductionReleaseUnitTest --tests "com.example.*"`
OR

> `./gradlew test+{build_type}+{build_flavor}+UnitTest --tests "com.example.*"`

This will only execute Production flavour Release build config unit test cases only in the `com.example` package directory.

Using the above Gradle script you can avoid running test cases in your library projects.